# Trouble with domain A-Records configuration

Tags: dns, web-hosting

I was trying to modify `A Records` for my domain name. i entered two different value in the name field inside `A Records`:

```
1. <balnk>.example.com
2. www.example.com
```

Now if i type `example.com` it doen't work but `www.example.com` works. How can i make `example.com` working ?

Comment: what did you mean `<balnk>` about?

Comment: i mean i left it blank without entering anything

Answer (score 1):

You should create A Record for naked domain with wildcard simbol `@`

```
@    A RECORD    127.0.0.1 (depending on your server ip)
www  CNAME       example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

More details about "how" you're trying to configure the A-records would be helpful (DNS application, web interface, etc.), but at its core, consider using the `@` configuration for your naked domain A-record (`example.com`), instead of a `<blank>`.

Separately, consider using a CNAME or other redirect for `www.example.com` to `example.com`.  Depending on your circumstances, putting some thought into these options may give you better results and/or performance.  Check [this page](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-between-a-cname-alias-url/) out for different redirection options and the implications.